# How does $n+2\mid(n^2+n+1)(n^2+n+2)$ imply $n+2\mid12$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to show that if $n+2\mid(n^2+n+1)(n^2+n+2)$, then $n+2 \mid 12$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far :)

Comment: Q: What do you get when you substitute $x=-2$ into
$$f(x)=(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+2)?$$
A: Same answer as timbuc, but with less calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint

$$(n^2+n+1)(n^2+n+2)=n^4+2n^3+4n^2+3n+2$$

and

$$ n^4+2n^3+4n^2+3n+2=(n+2)(n^3+4n-5)+12$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\,\ n\!+\!2\!:\,\ n\equiv -2\,\Rightarrow\, f(n)\equiv f(-2)\,$ for all polynomials $\,f\in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ a special case of the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825833/242)

Comment: @Readers See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2216759/242) for elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\displaystyle n^2+n=n(n+2)-(n+2)+2=(n+2)(n-1)+2$

$\displaystyle\implies (n^2+n+1)(n^2+n+2)=\{\underbrace{(n+2)(n-1)+2}+1\}\{\underbrace{(n+2)(n-1)+2}+2\}\equiv(2+1)(2+2)\pmod{(n+2)(n-1)}\equiv12\pmod{(n+2)} $

Comment: @markosi, How about this?

Comment: Remark that this method is implicitly using [congruence arithmetic,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/825833/242), i.e. $\,f(n) = g(n)h(n)\,\Rightarrow\,  {\rm mod}\ n\!+\!2\!:\ f(n)\equiv f(-2)\equiv g(-2)h(-2)\equiv 3\cdot 4\ \ $