# Prove $27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8\equiv 0\pmod{26460}$

Tags: divisibility, exponentiation

So far I've tried:

**1)** $26460 = 2^2 * 3^3 * 5 * 7^2$
**2)** $10152 = 2^3 * 3^3 * 47$
**3)** $27195 - 10887 = 16308 = 2^2 * 3^3 * 151$ *(I know $a^8 - b^8\equiv0\pmod{a - b}$)*

Therefore I conclude that $27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8$ is divisible by $2^2 * 3^3$, as well is **1)**.

But what about $5 * 7^2$ part?

Comment: These numbers aren't that big. Can you use a computer to solve the problem? Or even a calculator?

Comment: $27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 0^8 - 2^8 + 2^8 \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

Comment: Well I've used Wolfram to check if it's indeed divisible (it is), but the proof requires algebraic manipulation, no more no less. Tnx @Santiago, that helps, onto 7 now.

Comment: @iccthedral: notice that $10887 - 10152 = 735 = 7 \cdot 105$.

Comment: @Santiago All is clear now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $  [Exploit innate symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+%22innate+symmetry%22) using the following observation

$$\begin{eqnarray}a\equiv c,&&\ b\equiv d\!\!\pmod{m}\\
a\equiv d,&&\ b\equiv c\!\!\pmod{k}\end{eqnarray}\, \Rightarrow\,\ e := a^n+b^n-c^n-d^n\equiv 0\!\! \pmod{{\rm lcm}(m,k))}$$

because $\ \ {\rm mod}\ m\!:\ a\equiv c\,\Rightarrow a^n\equiv c^n,\ \ b\equiv d\,\Rightarrow\ b^n\equiv d^n\,\Rightarrow\,e\equiv 0\, $ by [Congruence Power Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242)

Similarly $\, {\rm mod}\ k\!:\,\ e\equiv 0.\ $ Thus $\ m,k\mid e\,\Rightarrow\,{\rm lcm}(m,k)\mid e$.

**Remark** $\ $ More generally, bringing to the fore the innate symmetry yields:

Assume  $ \{a,b\}\equiv \{c,d\}\ {\rm mod}\ m,k\ $ and $\,f(x,y)\,$ is symmetric $\,f(x,y)=f(y,x).$

Then $\,\ \ f(a,b)\equiv f(c,d)\ {\rm mod}\ m,k\,$ so also mod $\,{\rm lcm}(m,k).$

OP has  $\, f(x,y) = x^n + y^n.$

**Remark** $\ $ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1898438/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1209693/242) for some explicit examples.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=27195, b=10887, c=10152$ and consider this:
$$
\matrix{
m       &a \bmod m      &b \bmod m      &c \bmod m      \\
2^2     &3      &3      &0      \\
3^3     &6      &6      &0      \\
5\hphantom{^1}       &0      &2      &2      \\
7^2     &0      &9      &9      \\
}
$$
Note how for each $m$, we have $b \equiv a$ or $b \equiv c \bmod m$, and the other is $0 \bmod m$.

Therefore, the terms in $27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8$ reduce to $0 \bmod m$.

Comment: lhf, what does the matrix represent?

Comment: Haha, this is too clever to be used as my own proof, professor knows my wits :) Thank you nonetheless, I love the construction.

Comment: @iccthedral It's a classic exploitation of symmetry - I explain it further in my answer (esp. the linked example).  Once you see the innate symmetry it's not "too clever" but somewhat trivial.