# Show that $2007^{2013}-1974^{2013}-1946^{2013}+1913^{2013}$ is divisible by 2013

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $$N = 2007^{2013}-1974^{2013}-1946^{2013}+1913^{2013}$$
> Then select all the option(s) that are correct:
>
> 1. N is divisible by 61
> 2. N is divisible by 2013
> 3. N is divisible by 28
> 4. All of these

**My attempt**:
I tried to use the property $a^x - b^x = (a-b)(a^{x-1} + ... + b^{x-1})$ for odd x. Note that $2007 - 1946 = 61$ and $1974-1913 = 61$
$$N = 61(2007^{2012} +\ ...\ + 1946^{2012} - (1974^{2012} +\ ...\ + 1913^{2012})) $$
Option **1** is correct. However, the answer key says that $N$ is also divisible by $2013$. How do I prove this? Little fermat won't work because $2013$ is not prime.

Comment: You can use Euler's theorem as a generalization of Fermat's little theorem : If $a$ and $n$ are coprime, then $$a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$$ holds.

Comment: But if you have already established that the given number is divisible by $61$ , you only need to do that also for $11$ and $3$ considering $2013=3\cdot 11\cdot 61$ and the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: I added an answer that shows how it is a special case of a general result that makes the divisibilities obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$2013=61\cdot33.$$
Since $$2007-1946=1974-1913=61$$
and $$N=2007^{2013}-1946^{2013}-\left(1974^{2013}-1913^{2013}\right),$$ we see that $N$ is divisible by $61$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that $N$ is divisible by $33.$

Now, write $$N=2007^{2013}-1974^{2013}-\left(1946^{2013}-1913^{2013}\right).$$
Can you end it now?

Also, since $$N=2007^{2013}+1913^{2013}-\left(1946^{2013}+1974^{2013}\right),$$
we see that $N$ is divisible by $28$.

Comment: I don't quite see how the final grouping demonstrates that $N$ is divisible by $28$. (I do see that $2007\equiv1913$ and $1946\equiv1974$ mod $28$, but how does that help?)

Comment: @Barry Cipra $2013$ is odd and $2007+1913$ is divisible by $28.$ Also, $1946+1974$ is divisible by $28$. Now use $a^n+b^n=(a+b)(a^{n-1}-...+b^{n-1})$ for odd $n>1$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! (I also now see that I did my own arithmetic wrong: $2007\not\equiv1913$ mod $28$.)

Comment: @Barry Cipra   Thank you for your interest!

Comment: @BarryCipra See the final congruence in my answer for why it is true.

Comment: @BillDubuque, lovely.

Answer (score 2):

Corect is "All" by $\,m,n,d =\!\!\!\!\overbrace{ 61,33}^{\color{darkorange}{61(33)=2013}}\!\!\!\!,1913\,$ below, $ $  & $\bmod \color{darkorange}{28}\!:\ \color{#0a0}{m\!+\!n\!+\!2d}\equiv 5\!+\!5\!+\!2\cdot 9\equiv 0$

$$\begin{align}
 f\, =\  &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  2007^k  -\ \ \ \ \ 1974^k -\ \ \ 1946^k +1913^k\\[.1em]
   =\         &(\color{#c00}m\!+\!n\!+\!d)^k-(\color{#c00}m\!+\!d)^k-(n\!+\!d)^k+d^k\\[.2em]
{\large \Rightarrow}\ \ f\,\equiv\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ \  (n\!+\!d)^k \ \ \ \ -\ \ \ \ \  d^k\: - (n\!+\!d)^k + d^k\equiv 0\pmod{\!\color{#c00}m\!=\!\color{darkorange}{61}}\\[.1em]
\&\ \ \ f\,\equiv\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ (m\!+\!d)^k - (m\!+\!d)^k  \ \ \ \ - \ \ \  d^k\ +\ d^k\equiv 0\pmod{n\!=\!\color{darkorange}{33}}\\[.1em]
\&\ \ \ f\,\equiv\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (-d)^k\!\! +\! (-n\!-\!d)^k\! + (n\!+\!d)^k +\, d^k\equiv 0\pmod{\underbrace{\color{#0a0}{m\!+\!n\!+\!2d}}_{\textstyle \color{darkorange}{28}k\!\!\!}},\  {\rm by}\ \ k\ \rm odd
\end{align}\qquad$$

**Remark** $ $ Thus for any integers $\,m,n,d\,$ the above $\,f(m,n,d)\,$is divisible by $m,n$, and also by $\,m\!+\!n\!+\!2d$ if $k$ is odd. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1898438/242) for more on the innate *symmetry* at the heart of the matter.

Comment: I upvoted, very interesting.  With respect to my answer : (1) good catch (2) Your answer **does** focus on a general approach, making my answer obselete.  Therefore, I am going to delete my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks. Once the underlying **symmetry** is brought to the fore (see the linked post) it becomes obvious how to generalize such problems (and, alas, as is often the case, the "magic" disappears once one learns the "trick" and it appears then a bit trivial). But at least we can still appreciate the power that symmetry brings to the table - which is beautiful in itself (and more ubiquitous). As I often advise my students: [always exploit any innate symmetry!](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20exploit%20%22innate%20symmetry%22)