# Finding the remainder when $p(x^7)$ is divided by $p(x)$, where $p(x)=x^6+x^5+ \cdots + x + 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

I know there are one or two similar questions to this one but I did not want to look at them since I would like just a hint.

> Find the remainder when $p(x^7)$ is divided by $p(x)$, where $p(x)=x^6+x^5+ \cdots + x + 1$?

I wrote $p(x)= \dfrac {x^7-1}{x-1}$, so $p(x^7)=\dfrac {x^{49}-1}{x^7-1}$. We are looking for the unique polynomial $R(x)$ with $deg (R)<6$ such that

$$\dfrac {x^{49}-1}{x^7-1} =Q(x)\left(\dfrac {x^7-1}{x-1}\right)+R(x)$$

Multiplying both sides by $x^7-1$,

$$x^{49}-1=Q(x)p(x)(x^7-1)+R(x)(x^7-1)$$

I know one way to do it would be to find $R(x)$ at $6$ different points and then set up a system of $6$ equations. I want to plug in values which will make the $Q(x)$ term zero because I can't evaluate $Q(x)$. But the values which will make the $Q(x)$ term zero are the $7^{th}$ roots of unity, which will also make the $R(x)$ term zero.

Comment: polynomial remainder theorem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's tackle this with the notion of congruences. In the polynomial ring, $f(x)\equiv g(x)\pmod{m(x)}$ means that $f(x)-g(x)=m(x)q(x)$ for some
polynomial $q(x)$.

Here
$$x^7=1+(x-1)p(x)\equiv1\pmod{p(x)}.$$
So $x^{14}\equiv(x^7)^2\equiv1^2\pmod{p(x)}$ etc. Similarly, $x^{7k}\equiv1\pmod {p(x)}$.

But you are after $p(x^7)$ modulo $p(x)$. But $p(x^7)=x^{42}+x^{35}+x^{28}+x^{21}+x^{14}+x^7+1$. This should be
easy to tackle now...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\bmod p\!:\,\  \color{#c00}{x^7 \equiv  1} \Rightarrow\, p(\color{#c00}{x^7}) \equiv p(\color{#c00}1)\ $ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825833/242)

Or, without congruences put $\,y=x^7\,$ in $\,y\!-\!1\mid p(y)-p(1)\,$ by the Factor Theorem.

Comment: Note: the linked proofs of the Congruence Rules are given for integers but it is clear that they work in any commutative ring, since the use only commutative ring axioms.

Comment: Your answers are really pleasing to eyes, really nice use of colour.

Answer (score 3):

One trick is to think of modular artithmetic (in the ring of rational polynomials):

$$x^7\equiv 1\pmod{1+x+\cdots+x^6}$$

So $$p(x^7)\equiv p(1)\pmod{1+x+\cdots+x^6}$$

Basically, this is true for *any* polynomial $p$.

In this case, $p(1)=7$, which is your remainder.

Comment: Is $$\sin (x^7) \equiv \sin(1) \pmod{1+x+\cdots+x^6}$$ true ?

Comment: $\sin$ is not a polynomial. @123 So you'd need to know what ring you were in to define $\equiv$.

Comment: In particular, the value $\sin(x^7)-\sin(1)$ is not a finite sum of values divisible by $x^7-1$, but rather, an infinite sum, so divisibility is problematic.

Comment: But the basic answer is "no, we wouldn't write $\sin(x^7)\equiv \sin(1)$ in general." @123

Comment: @123 Your query above is clarified by the proof of the Polynomial Congruence Rule linked in my answer (which, as  I mention, is valid in any commutative ring)

Answer (score 3):

Write $p(x^7) = q(x)p(x) +r(x)$ where $deg(r) <7$.

If we say $1,a_1,...a_6$ are all zeros (which are obviously different) of $x^7=1$ then for each $i$ we get:
$$  p(1) = p(a_i^7) = q(a_i)p(a_i) +r(a_i) = r(a_i)$$

Thus $r$ takes the same value for 6 different values and thus $r(x) \equiv  p(1) =7$.