# Show divisibility $\,1998\mid 760^{1998} - 20^{1998} + 1910^{1998} - 652^{1998}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Show the number $N = 760^{1998} - 20^{1998} + 1910^{1998} - 652^{1998}$ is divisible by 1998. I tried to factor in the numbers and use Euler's theorem as I am applying?

Comment: Note:  Google translates this as "


How to solve it? Show the number $N = 760 ^ {1998} - 20 ^ {1998} + 1910 ^ {998} - 652 ^ {19998}$ is divisible by $1998$

I tried to factor in the numbers and use Euler's theorem as I am applying?"

Comment: Other Note:  I question some of these exponents.  As it stands the claim does not appear to be true.  [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+760+%5E+1998+-+20+%5E+1998+%2B+1910+%5E+998+-+652+%5E+19998+mod+1998) gets the result $678$.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I've already corrected! Forgiveness for what happenedI've already corrected! Forgiveness for what happened

Comment: I added an answer exploiting symmetry. You can find many similar examples in [prior answers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+symmetric+mod+polynomial+-wilson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1998=2\times 27\times 37$ .
$N = 760^{1998} - 20^{1998} + 1910^{1998} - 652^{1998}$ 
Since all the constituents of N are even, It is enough to prove that $999\mid N$, which is equivalent to proving that $27\mid N$ and $37\mid N$ as $(27,37)=1$.
Note that, $$760\equiv 20 \pmod {37}$$ and $$1910\equiv 652 \pmod {37}$$.
 Hence  $760^{1998}\equiv 20^{1998}\pmod {37}$ and $1910^{1998}\equiv 652^{1998} \pmod {37}$. Also note that $\varphi(27)=18$ and  $18\mid 1998$ and $(760,27)=(20,27)=(1910,27)=(652,27)=1$. Now use Euler's theorem to complete the proof. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: There is an underlying symmetry that makes it very simple - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem enjoys innate $\rm\color{#c00}{symmetry}$ that greatly simplifies matters once brought to the fore.

$\quad\phantom{\Rightarrow}\ \  \{ 760,\ \ \ \ 1910\}\ \  \equiv\, \{20,\ \ \ 652\}\ \ \ \ {\rm mod}\,\ 27\ \&\ 37,\ $ by $\ \ \begin{align}&760,\,1910\,\equiv\, 652,\, 20\,\bmod{27}\\ &760,\,1910\,\equiv\, 20,\, 652\,\bmod{37}\end{align}$

$\quad\Rightarrow\ \{760^n,\ \ 1910^n\} \equiv \{20^n,\ \,652^n\}\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ 27 \ \&\ 37,\ $ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825833/242)

$\quad\Rightarrow\ \ \ 760^n\!+\! 1910^n\ \ \equiv \ \ 20^n\!+652^n\ \ \,{\rm mod}\,\ 27\ \&\ 37,\  $ so also $\,{\rm mod}\ 999 = {\rm lcm}(27,37) = 27(37)$

since addition $\,f(x,y)\, =\, x + y\ $ is $\rm\color{#c00}{symmetric}$  $\,f(x,y)= f(y,x),\, $  so its value depends only upon the (multi-)set $\,\{x,\ y\}.\, $   Parity $\,\Rightarrow\,$ congruence is true mod $2,\,$ so also mod  $\,2\cdot 999 = 1998.\,\ $ **QED**

**Remark** $ $ Generally if a polynomial $\,f\in\Bbb Z[x,y]\,$ is $\rm\color{#c00}{symmetric}$ then as above we deduce

$$\begin{align} \{A, B\}\, &\equiv\, \{a,b\}\ \pmod{\ m\ \ \&\ \ n}\\[.5em] 
\Rightarrow\  f(A,B)&\equiv f(a,b)\, \pmod{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

a generalization of  [CCRT =constant-case optimization  of CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860148/242) = Chinese Remainder,  plus a generalization of the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) to (symmetric) bivariate polynomials.

You can find many similar symmetric problems in [prior answers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+symmetric+mod+polynomial+-wilson)